# Capitalize the first letter in a ArrayList of names

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I need to capitalize the first name, and last name in a ArrayList, Example:

input:

```
colette Sapienza
gretta Beumer
EMManuel Mossman
Colette Sapienza
```

Output:

```
Colete Sapienza
Gretta Beumer
Emmanuel Mossman
Colette Sapienza
```

Code:

```
ArrayList<String> a;
a = getNames();


for(int i=0; i < a.size(); i++){ 
  if(i==0)
    a.set(i, a.get(i).toUpperCase());
  else if (i > 0 && i-1 ==' ')
    a.set(i, a.get(i).toUpperCase());
  else
    a.set(i,a.get(i).toLowerCase());
}

return a;
```

Comment: Your post does not contain a question at all. Neither did you attach useful, complete method source code.

Comment: So, what is a question? Please tell us more about the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want to iterate the names in the `List` and capitalize the first letter of each name (and lower case the rest of each name). You could use [`Character.toUpperCase(char)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#toUpperCase%28char%29), [`String.substring(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int%29) and [`String.toLowerCase()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toLowerCase%28%29) and something like,

```
List<String> al = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("colette Sapienza",
        "gretta Beumer", "EMManuel Mossman", "Colette Sapienza"));
for (int index = 0; index < al.size(); index++) {
    String name = al.get(index);
    String[] names = name.split("\\s+");
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
        if (i != 0) {
            sb.append(' ');
        }
        sb.append(Character.toUpperCase(names[i].charAt(0)));
        sb.append(names[i].substring(1).toLowerCase());
    }
    al.set(index, sb.toString());
}
System.out.println(al);
```

Output is

```
[Colette Sapienza, Gretta Beumer, Emmanuel Mossman, Colette Sapienza]
```

Comment: Or he could use http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/text/WordUtils.html :D.